# How do I use MySQL Left Join to get results based on another table row's id?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am building a custom forum in CodeIgniter.  I have four primary tables: parents(categories), children(boards), threads, and messages(replies).  The thread table only contains the thread id, author, title, date, and the id of the first message.  When a thread is viewed, it takes the column "first_msg_id" to retrieve the content of the thread.

I would like to create a query that gets the count of all the replies in a specific board.  Basically, any message that doesn't match a thread's first_msg_id field.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$query = "
                    SELECT
                        m.message_id, m.thread_id
                        t.thread_id, t.first_msg_id
                    FROM forum_messages AS m
                        LEFT JOIN forum_threads AS t ON t.first_msg_id != m.message_id
                    WHERE t.child_id = ".$board_id."
                    ORDER BY m.message_id";
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.thread_id, t.first_msg_id FROM forum_messages AS m ' at line 3
```

Here are my tables:
[image]
[image]

## Update

Ok, so now that I got my query working(well, fixed the error), it's not doing what I want... I think I have my logic wrong.  I wrote a script that created 40 new threads in one board.  None of them have replies.  When I use mysql num rows with the query I made, I get a result of 1560.  It should return 0.  Why is this happening???  Lol.

Got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma after `m.thread_id`

Something like

```
SELECT
    m.message_id, m.thread_id,
    t.thread_id, t.first_msg_id
FROM forum_messages AS m
    LEFT JOIN forum_threads AS t ON t.first_msg_id != m.message_id
WHERE t.child_id = ".$board_id."
ORDER BY m.message_id
```

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error, but now I am getting something completely different. Check the edit I made to my question

Answer (score 1):

Comma missing `,` after `m.thread_id`

Try with -

```
$query = "SELECT m.message_id, m.thread_id, t.thread_id, t.first_msg_id ....
```

More appropriate -

```
$query = "
         SELECT
         m.message_id, m.thread_id,
                                  ^
         -------------------------|
         t.thread_id, t.first_msg_id
         FROM forum_messages AS m
         LEFT JOIN forum_threads AS t ON t.first_msg_id != m.message_id
         WHERE t.child_id = ".$board_id."
         ORDER BY m.message_id
         ";
```

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error, but now I am getting something completely different.  Check the edit I made to my question.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 can you please clarify a little more...from your question ..query seems ok to me..let me know if im missing some part..can u plz paste a design schema here or create a fiddle